# Is there a way to dynamically create a table in Angular 5 - unknown rows and column size

Tags: angular

Hello I have been searching for a way to dynamically create an angular 5 component which can create a table with a variable length of rows and columns. It always varies.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Define an array of row names and and array of column names. Then iterate over them in your template. Since arrays are dynamic, you have a dynamic table.

Comment: Is there a live example I can look at ? I am pretty visual.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to 'dynamically create' the Angular component.

As another user mentioned, you will:

1. Provide data that represents rows and columns of arbitrary lengths to an Angular component

   - You may need a mechanism in the component to:

     - Change the component's data itself to different row/column lengths
     - Find different sources of data that are different row/column lengths and replace or update the component's data (e.g. Requests to different API URLs or opening different local JSON files)
2. Build a related component template that will iterate over the data provided to the component

[This Angular Material stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xvqkarbymrl?file=app%2Ftable-dynamic-columns-example.html) sourced from [Angular Material table component examples](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) should illustrate the basic premise in code to suit your visual needs.

My only warning is that some of the elements or attributes used might be specific to Angular Material and the example itself is Angular 6 ***but*** the general data consumption in the component and iteration logic in the template (e.g. `*ngFor`) will be the same in typical generic Angular 5 usage.

If this isn't satisfactory, you may need to edit your question to add a bit more detail or other specifics.